# Best practice for scheduling an event in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, cron

What I currently have is a website where admins can create polls. On a poll, they can set a date on when it should end

What I'm aiming to do is on that time that the poll ends, the winner is found (alternative vote method, so a little more work than just tallying up votes) and the status of the poll is changed (this is just a bool)

My current thoughts are to create a cron task when submitting a poll, to be run at the time given. this will just run something like `php app/console Poll:FindWinner --my_argument=pollGUID`, and my php will find the winner of the given poll and change the status. There could be multiple polls running at once, and possibly multiple dates down the line (eg a date to end the poll on, and a date to display the winner until)

Should a poll be deleted or edited, the cron task would be changed respectively

The only other alternative that I can think of is creating a mysql scheduled event, but I don't think that's a good idea

Is there a better solution for what I'm trying to accomplish? This **isn't** something that will be run periodically, it must only be done at the datetime provided

Comment: Have *one* general cron task which runs every so often and processes *all* polls which have finished since the last time. – Alternatively, if there's no action that needs to be taken *at that time* (like notifying winners), simply don't do anything at that time and calculate the data the first time anyone asks to see it.

Comment: I considered that, but it seemed... wasteful(?) to check periodically like that - I've never done something like this though, so if that's generally what people would do, so be it. My concern is updating/deleting existing tasks that got queued, if an admin decides to extend the length of a poll (I'm comfortable doing this in PHP as I'd just name the tasks after the Poll's GUID so they'd be easy to find/update/delete, but not so much with cron itself)

Comment: That's why you simply check occasionally whether something has finished, and if so process it. Much simpler than scheduling individual jobs beforehand. Think less stateful. In terms of wastefulness… your server going "hmm, nothing to do, let's sleep" once every minute or so takes absolutely no resources whatsoever.

Comment: It would have to query my table for that every minute or so though, no?

Comment: Probably, yes. But if that takes any significant resources, you're doing something wrong.